# UNIX / Linux signals

Tags: unix, signals

Can someone tell me, as to why program1's signal handler is not working?

```
Program1: signal1.c
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <signal.h>

 void handler(int sig)
 {
  printf("Caught signal: %d",sig);
  signal(sig,handler);
 }

 int main()
 {
  struct sigaction sa;
  sa.sa_handler=handler;
  sa.sa_sigaction=NULL;
  sigaction(SIGRTMIN,&sa,NULL);
  kill(0,SIGRTMIN);
 }



Actual Output:
# ./a.out 
  Real-time signal 0

Expected Output:
  Caught signal: 34
```

Please help me to resolve Program1

However, the program2 works, if i use a simple signal handler like as usual:

```
enter code here
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

void handler(int sig)
{
 printf("Caught signal: %d\n",sig);
 signal(sig,handler);
}

int main()
{
signal(SIGRTMIN, handler);
kill(0,SIGRTMIN);
}

Output:
Caught signal: 34
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `sa_handler` and `sa_sigaction` are members of the same union:

```
struct sigaction {
    union {
      __sighandler_t _sa_handler;
      void (*_sa_sigaction)(int, struct siginfo *, void *);
    } _u;
    sigset_t sa_mask;
    unsigned long sa_flags;
    void (*sa_restorer)(void);
};

#define sa_handler  _u._sa_handler
#define sa_sigaction    _u._sa_sigaction
```

So that when you set `sa_sigaction` it overwrites `sa_handler` value.

Comment: @Maxim : http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sigaction.2.html, this link says it is not a union?

Comment: @Maxim: Although it works when i comment out "sa.sa_sigaction=NULL"

Comment: From the link: ***"On some architectures a union is involved: do not assign to both sa_handler and sa_sigaction."***

Comment: @Maxim: So the method to catch signals using methods1 or 2 is an alternate? I mean any one we can use? Which one is more preferable?

Comment: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/signal.html : _"The sigaction() function provides a more comprehensive and reliable mechanism for controlling signals; new applications should use sigaction() rather than signal()."_

Comment: Huge lot of thanks, Maxim. It was really helpful. Thank you so much :-)

Comment: You might also like this http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_04.html#tag_02_04